# Checkout page The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources

Tags: checkout, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5

I am recently updated Magento Enterprise edition from 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.5, after successfully upgrade I am facing the following error during the checkout.

**The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.**

```
http://{{base_url}}/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/totals?_=1662369155460
http://{{base_url}}/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information
```

I've disabled all my custom & third-party modules.

Also enabled the "Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens" from backend (system->configuration->services->OAuth).

FYI I've attached screen.

Note : If i used the default magento database then the order flow working & created a new order without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources` error is a well-known head-scratcher. I have [this forum post](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/REST-API-The-consumer-isn-t-authorized-to-access-resources-2-3-1/td-p/133545) in my Notes file because this error has some unintuitive solutions, though there seem to be many root causes.

- It seems that some PHP installs return this error *either* on FastCGI *or* FPM. Did you update Apache / Nginx together with Magento (perhaps in Docker)? If so, try switching from/to FastCGI or FPM.
- Update to the latest supported PHP version for your Magento version. That's likely to be either PHP 7.4 or 8.0. **No Magento version supports PHP 8.0**.